# cannot GET undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, get, undefined

Hi I am developing my own portfolio with HTML CSS and JavaScript, and I added some transition animations. Everything works fine until i click on another hyperlink, where the transitions runs well but afterwards my page goes blank and it shows the following error: 'cannot GET undefined'.

index.html: Just a simple home page with some hyperlinks, my CSS and JavaScript are linked correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="transitions.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

        <div class="transition transition-1 is-active"></div>

        <section>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="/"><span>HOME</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html"><span>ABOUT</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html"><span>CONTACT</span></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><span>GITHUB</span></a></li>
            </ul>


            <h1>Mateo Ghidini | Web Developer</h1>
        </section>
    

  <script src="main.js"></script>  

</body>
```

transitions.css:

```
.transition-1{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index: 101;
    background-color: var(--dark);
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}

.transition-1.is-active{
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: all;
}


.transition-2{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:-100%;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    z-index: 101;
    background-color: var(--dark);
    
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}

.transition-2.is-active{
    left:0px;
}


.transition-3{
    position:fixed;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:100%;
    z-index: 101;
    background-color: var(--dark);
    
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}

.transition-3.is-active{
    top:0px;
}
```

main.js:

```
window.onload=() =>{
    
    const transition_el = document.querySelector('.transition');
    const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a'); 
    setTimeout(()=>{
        transition_el.classList.remove('is-active');
    }, 500);

    for(let i = 0; i<anchors.length; i++){
        const anchor = anchors[i];

        anchor.addEventListener('click', e =>{
            e.preventDefault();
            let target = e.target.href;

            transition_el.classList.add('is-active');

            setTimeout(()=>{
                window.location.href = target;
            },500);
        });
    }
}
```

i hope someone could help to solve this issue, cause i have no knowledge about this error.

Comment: _"Shows the following error..."_ where? The browser console? In the page itself?

Comment: @Phil thanks for commenting, the error is shown in the browser, after the transition the page comes blank and the error appears. for example, i go to localhost:8000/about.html by clicking in a hyperlink, and instead of having my html with styles i have a blank page with the error

Comment: Sounds like an error from your HTTP server in that case. Check your logs for whatever is running on port 8000

Comment: is not the port, it is just an example. Im runing a simple html with live server in visua studio @Phil

Comment: I never said it was the port, I said to check the logs for whatever is running on that port

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the target in `e.target.href` is the `<span>` tag instead of the `<a>` tag, which doesn't have a href.

Removing the spans from inside the links will work, such as using [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead of `target`.

```js
anchor.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let target = e.currentTarget.href;
  // etc...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct property for event argument should be

```
e.currentTarget.href
```

main.js

```
window.onload = () => {
  const transition_el = document.querySelector(".transition");
  const anchors = document.querySelectorAll("a");
  setTimeout(() => {
    transition_el.classList.remove("is-active");
  }, 500);

  for (let i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    const anchor = anchors[i];
    anchor.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      let target = e.currentTarget.href;

      transition_el.classList.add("is-active");

      setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.href = target;
      }, 500);
    });
  }
};
```